# Amazon S3 client connect through proxy - putObject getting NullPointerException

Tags: proxy, amazon-s3, amazon-web-services

I've got this simple piece of code which is trying to upload a file to Amazon S3 via a proxy. This is the code:

```
    BasicAWSCredentials basicCred = new BasicAWSCredentials("my_access_key", "my_secret_key");
    ClientConfiguration clientCfg = new ClientConfiguration();
    clientCfg.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTP);

    //setup proxy connection:
    clientCfg.setProxyHost("192.168.2.12");
    clientCfg.setProxyPort(80);




    AmazonS3 s3 = new AmazonS3Client(basicCred, clientCfg);


    String bucketName = "mybucket";
    String key = "/test/Capture.JPG";
    File file = new File("d:/Test_Data/Capture.JPG");

    System.out.println("Uploading a new object to S3 from a file");
    s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest(bucketName, key, file));
```

However this is the error I got from running the program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.amazonaws.util.BinaryUtils.fromHex(BinaryUtils.java:69)
    at com.amazonaws.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1066)
    at javaapplication8.JavaApplication8.main(JavaApplication8.java:48)
Java Result: 1
```

I'm using the latest aws 1.3.8 sdk from amazon. The proxy is set up in another PC next to me and it's just a simple Javascript proxy (http://www.catonmat.net/http-proxy-in-nodejs/)

I can't figure it out why. Somebody can help me, please?

Comment: After further investigation, I found out that it was the hexData is null in the function:

public static byte[] fromHex(String hexData) from BinaryUtils.java line 69.

Its that any other ways where I can get more debug information?

Comment: UPDATE: I had the same problem with AWS SDK 1.6.7, it seems to be all working now after an update to 1.9.35

Answer (score 9):

here is another approach,

```
ClientConfiguration config = new ClientConfiguration();
config.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);
config.setProxyHost("YOUR_PROXY_IP");
config.setProxyPort(YOUR_PROXY_PORT);

BasicAWSCredentials creds = new BasicAWSCredentials("YOUR_KEY", "YOUR_SECRET"); 
s3Client = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
                .withClientConfiguration(config)
                .withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_2)
                .withCredentials(new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds))                   
                .build();
```

Comment: It worked for me. I was working on a sample application in my organization where I ran into this issue. Configuring the proxy worked!

Answer (score 3):

I ran into this issue as well. I stepped through everything in a debugger and found that the cause of the problem is the Amazon S3 client code expecting a header tag called `"ETag"`, but the response contains `"Etag"`, with a lowercase `"t"`.

The headers are put into a `Map<String,String>`, so when the Amazon S3 client code calls `get("ETag")`, it gets back `null`, which is then fed into the `hexData()` method and blows up.

This seems to happen to a number of people using non-Amazon S3 services or accessing Amazon's AWS S3 service through a web proxy.

I don't know of a fix other than grabbing the Amazon client source, changing the `Headers.ETAG` value to `"Etag"` and building the `JAR` yourself.

Comment: I did provide an answer, just not a simple one. It requires rebuilding the S3 client JAR. I would hope there's a better answer somewhere out there.

Answer (score 0):

Change the protocol to HTTPS.

$clientCfg.setProtocol(Protocol.HTTPS);

Comment: Please be aware that the question dates from 2012, where using HTTP**S** connection wasn't widely used as it is nowadays.